# Does conversion between alias types in Go create copies?

Tags: string, go, type-conversion, type-alias

Example:

```
type MyString string 
var s = "very long string"
var ms = MyString(s)
var s2 = string(s)
```

Are `ms` or `s2` a full copy of `s` (as it would be done with `[]byte(s)`)? Or they are just a string struct copies (which keeps the real value in a pointer)?

What if we are passing this to a function? E.g.:

```
func foo(s MyString){
  ...
}
foo(ms(s))  // do we copy s here?
```

Comment: It helps to remember that *everything* in Go is a value, and all assignments are a copy of that value. `foo(ms(s))` does make a copy, but not because of the conversion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Spec: Conversions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

> Specific rules apply to (non-constant) conversions between numeric types or to and from a string type. These conversions may change the representation of `x` and incur a run-time cost. **All other conversions only change the type but not the representation of `x`.**

So converting to and from the underlying type of your custom type does not make a copy of it.

When you pass a value to a function or method, a copy is made and passed. If you pass a `string` to a function, only the structure describing the `string` will be copied and passed, since `string`s are immutable.

Same is true if you pass a slice (slices are also descriptors). Passing a slice will make a copy of the slice descriptor but it will refer to the same underlying array.

Comment: This is correct. Here is some `unsafe.Pointer` hacking to prove that the string headers are indeed the same: http://play.golang.org/p/0khVz09-Jc.

Comment: Nothing in the quoted passage mentions copying.