# GoLang: Memory allocation for type inheritance and casting in Go

Tags: go

In Go if I have a custom type inherited from let's say a slice of integers if I cast an array of integers to my custom type would it involve new memory allocation?

http://play.golang.org/p/cNpKELZ3X- :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyIntsArray []int

func (a MyIntsArray) Sum() int {
    sum := 0
    for _, i := range a {
        sum += i
    }
    return sum
}

func main() {
    myInts := []int{1,2,3,5,7,11}
    myIntsArr := MyIntsArray(myInts)
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("myInts: %v, myIntsArr: %v, Sum: %v", myInts, myIntsArr, myIntsArr.Sum()))
}
```

**Update**: OK, for slices there is no memory allocation as slices are pointers.

But I have more general question. How about structs? Seems it makes copy: http://play.golang.org/p/NXgM8Cr-qj and it is because of working with value types.

I am trying to figure out if I can cast a pointer to a struct to a pointer of a different type. Something like this: http://play.golang.org/p/BV086ZAeGf

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyType1 struct {
    Val int
    Values []int
}

type MyType2 MyType1

func main() {
    t1 := &MyType1{Val: -1, Values: []int{1,3,5}}
    var t2 *MyType2 
    t2 = *MyType2(t1)
    fmt.Printf("t1: %v, t2: %v\n", t1, t2)
    t1.Val = -10
    t1.Values[1] = 200
    fmt.Printf("t1: %v, t2: %v\n", t1, t2)
}

prog.go:17: cannot convert t1 (type *MyType1) to type MyType2
prog.go:17: invalid indirect of MyType2(t1) (type MyType2)
```

Comment: There is no such thing as type inheritance. This is type conversion. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does convertion between alias types in Go create copies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253768/does-convertion-between-alias-types-in-go-create-copies)

Comment: try printf with "%p" with their pointers and you shall see it yourself

Comment: No it will not. You can change value in myInts and it will by applied to myIntsArr as well. @Anzel answer is also one method of checking.

Comment: OK, it's valid for slice, but I have more general question. How about structs? Seems it makes copy: http://play.golang.org/p/NXgM8Cr-qj but it's because of working with value types.

 I am trying to figure if I can cast a pointer to a struct to a pointer of a different type. Something like this: http://play.golang.org/p/FwM9dv-j_7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would compile with just

```
t2 = (*MyType2)(t1)
```

http://play.golang.org/p/lUGo-mxAOa

Comment: I love stack overflow, this gets two votes and an accepted response, while I got one vote, while explaining stuff, plus fixing your problem. I guess this is the world we live in, every one just wants copy paste code and no thinking. Good work on your career, op.

Comment: @Radoo Sure your answer is more comprehensive. I will vote it up now.

Answer (score 5):

No. You will work on the same memory. Slices are pointers, so the default "copying" of a slice means copying the address itself, not the value found at that address.

http://play.golang.org/p/vy-c7sS9Fz

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyIntsArray []int

func (a MyIntsArray) Sum() int {
    sum := 0
    for _, i := range a {
        sum += i
    }
    return sum
}

func main() {
    myInts := []int{1,2,3,5,7,11}
    myIntsArr := MyIntsArray(myInts)
    fmt.Printf("myInts: %v, %p, myIntsArr: %v, %p, Sum: %v\n", myInts, myInts, myIntsArr, myIntsArr, myIntsArr.Sum())
    for i, _ := range myInts {
        fmt.Printf("myInt: %v, %p, myIntsArr elem: %v, %p\n", myInts[i], &myInts[i], myIntsArr[i], &myIntsArr[i])
    }
    myInts[0] = 100
    fmt.Printf("myInts: %v, %p, myIntsArr: %v, %p, Sum: %v\n", myInts, myInts, myIntsArr, myIntsArr, myIntsArr.Sum())
    myIntsArr[1] = 200
    fmt.Printf("myInts: %v, %p, myIntsArr: %v, %p, Sum: %v\n", myInts, myInts, myIntsArr, myIntsArr, myIntsArr.Sum())
}
```

As you can see, all the addresses are identical for each element, and when you change one value from one variable item, the same value is available on the other.

Comment: Ok, for slices it's reasonable. But I've tried for structs and seems it does create a copy: http://play.golang.org/p/NXgM8Cr-qj

Comment: In that struct you have a slice which is a pointer. It's the same thing. That slice will be the same. For the int, float, string, the value is copied, for the slice, map, pointer the value/address of the pointer is copied. You must create a clone function, where you create a new struct with a new slice, and then, for each slice element copy the value from the source struct slice.

Comment: Wait, I might have misunderstood the question. :) You have a pointer cast. That's in example you commented at the top not in the comment you put here.

Comment: This is the fix on your example where you get the error. You can't cast to struct from a pointer, you either work with pointers or with non-pointer types http://play.golang.org/p/0t_vBFGFaI

Answer (score 0):

Go doesn't support casting between pointers to different structs. If you really want to you can use `unsafe` package which contains special type `unsafe.Pointer` which supports operations that no other type does:

> - A pointer value of any type can be converted to a Pointer.
> - A Pointer can be converted to a pointer value of any type.
> - A uintptr can be converted to a Pointer.
> - A Pointer can be converted to a uintptr.

http://play.golang.org/p/fhOptEOQ74

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type MyType1 struct {
    Val int
    Values []int32
}

type MyType2 struct {
    Val int
    Values []float32
}

func main() {
    t1 := &MyType1{Val: -1, Values: []int32{1,3,5}}
    p := unsafe.Pointer(t1)
    var t2 *MyType2 = (*MyType2)(p)
    fmt.Printf("t1: %v, t2: %v\n", t1, t2)

    t1.Val = -10
    t1.Values[1] = 200
    fmt.Printf("t1: %v, t2: %v\n", t1, t2)

    t2.Val = -20
    t2.Values[1] = 1.2345
    fmt.Printf("t1: %v, t2: %v\n", t1, t2)
}
```

The code will print:

```
t1: &{-1 [1 3 5]}, t2: &{-1 [1e-45 4e-45 7e-45]}
t1: &{-10 [1 200 5]}, t2: &{-10 [1e-45 2.8e-43 7e-45]}
t1: &{-20 [1 1067320345 5]}, t2: &{-20 [1e-45 1.2345 7e-45]}
```