# The difference between t and *t

Tags: string, pointers, go, methods, stack-overflow

```
package main

import "fmt"

type TT struct {
    a int
    b float32
    c string
}

func (t *TT) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%+v", *t)
}

func main() {
    tt := &TT{3, 4, "5"}
    fmt.Printf(tt.String())
}
```

The code can work well. But if I change the `String` method as in the following, it will cause dead loop. The difference is that the `*t` is replaced with `t`. Why?

```
func (t *TT) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%+v", t)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package checks if the value being printed has a `String() string` method (or in other words: if it implements the [`fmt.Stringer`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) interface), and if so, it will be called to get the `string` representation of the value.

This is documented in the `fmt` package doc:

> [...] If an operand implements method String() string, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).

Here:

```
return fmt.Sprintf("%+v", *t)
```

You are passing a value `*t` of type `TT` to the `fmt` package. If the `TT.String()` method has a pointer receiver, then the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of the type `TT` **does not include** the `String()` method, so the `fmt` package will not call it (only the method set of `*TT` includes it).

If you change the receiver to non-pointer type, then the method set of the type `TT` **will include** the `String()` method, so the `fmt` package will call that, but this is the method we're currently in, so that's an endless "indirect recursion".

#### Prevention / protection

If for some reason you do need to use the same receiver type as the type of the value you pass to the `fmt` package, an easy and common way to avoid this / protect from it is to create a new type with the [`type`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) keyword, and use type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) on the value being passed:

```
func (t TT) String() string {
    type TT2 TT
    return fmt.Sprintf("%+v", TT2(t))
}
```

Try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/C0hs9WroVt).

But why does this work? Because the `type` keyword creates a new type, and the new type will have **zero** methods (it does not "inherit" the methods of the underlying type).

Does this incur some run-time overhead? No. Quoting from [Spec: Type declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations):

> Specific rules apply to (non-constant) conversions between numeric types or to and from a string type. These conversions may change the representation of `x` and incur a run-time cost. **All other conversions only change the type but not the representation of `x`.**

Read more about this here: [Does convertion between alias types in Go create copies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253768/does-convertion-between-alias-types-in-go-create-copies/32253871#32253871)