# Typecasting in Golang

Tags: json, pointers, go, syntax, type-conversion

I was reading this following article:
https://www.ribice.ba/golang-enums/

There is a function defined in one of the code samples:

```
func (lt *LeaveType) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    // Define a secondary type to avoid ending up with a recursive call to json.Unmarshal
    type LT LeaveType;
    var r *LT = (*LT)(lt);
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &r)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    switch *lt {
    case AnnualLeave, Sick, BankHoliday, Other:
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New("Inalid leave type")
}
```

What is the syntax `var r *LT = (*LT)(lt);` doing in this example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go technically does not have *casts* but rather *conversions*.  The syntax for an explicit conversion is `T(x)` where `T` is some type and `x` is some value that is convertible to that type.  See [Conversions in the Go specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) for details.

As you can see from the function's declaration:

> ```
> func (lt *LeaveType) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
> ```

`lt` itself has type *pointer to `LeaveType`* and `UnmarshalJSON` is a *receiver function* for type `*LeaveType`.  The `encoding/json` package will call such a function to decode input JSON when the variable that the package would like to set has type `LeaveType` (or `*LeaveType`—the package will create the `LeaveType` variable itself in this case).

As the comment in the code says, the author of the code would now like to have the `encoding/json` code unmarshal the JSON *as if* there weren't a function `UnmarshalJSON`.  But there *is* a function `UnmarshalJSON`, so if we just invoke the `encoding/json` code without a little bit of trickery, `encoding/json` will just call this function again, leading to infinite recursion.

By defining a *new* type `LT` whose contents are exactly the same as the existing type `LeaveType`, we end up with a new type that *does not* have a receiver function.  Invoking the `encoding/json` on an instance of this type (or of a pointer to this type) *won't* call the `*LeaveType` receiver, because `LT` is a different type, even though its *contents* match up exactly.

We could do this:

```
func (lt *LeaveType) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    type LT LeaveType
    var r LT
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &r)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // ...
}
```

This would fill in `r`, which has the same size and shape as any `LeaveType` variable.  Then we could use the filled-in `r` to set `*lt`:

```
*lt = LeaveType(r) // an ordinary conversion
```

after which we could keep going as before, using `*lt` as the value.  But this means that `UnmarshalJSON` had to set a temporary variable `r`, which we then had to copy to its final destination.  Why not, instead, set up something so that `UnmarshalJSON` fills in the target variable, but using the type we chose?

That's what the syntax here is *for*.  It's not the *shortest* version: as Cerise Limón noted, there is a shorter way to spell it (and that shorter spelling is generally preferred).  The first set of parentheses in `(*LT)(lt)` is required to bind the `*`—the *pointer to* part—to the `LT`, as `*LT(lt)` has the wrong binding: it means the same thing as `*(LT(lt))` which is not what we want.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the detailed breakdown. I'm just learning Go and trying to wrap my head around the syntax. I was getting confused between type assertions (with the dot syntax) and type conversions. Also the parentheses around the pointer part makes sense!

Answer (score 6):

The expression `(*LT)(lt)` is a [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to type `*LT`.

The statement `var r *LT = (*LT)(lt);` declares variable `r` as type `*LT` with initial value `(*LT)(lt)`.  The statement can be written more simply as `r := (*LT)(lt)`.  There's no need to mention the type twice or to end the line with a semicolon.

The function declares type `LT` with empty method set to avoid a recursive call to `UnMarshalJSON`.

Answer (score 4):

[`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) unmarshals some JSON text into a Go value. If the value to unmarshal into implements the [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface, its `UnmarshalJSON()` method is called which allows to implement custom unmarshaling logic.

Quoting from `json.Unmarshal()`:

> To unmarshal JSON into a value implementing the Unmarshaler interface, Unmarshal calls that value's UnmarshalJSON method, including when the input is a JSON null.

The `json.Unmarshaler` interface:

```
type Unmarshaler interface {
    UnmarshalJSON([]byte) error
}
```

`LeaveType` (or more specifically `*LeaveType`) has an `UnmarshalJSON()` method which we can see in the question, so it implements `json.Unmarshaler`.

And the `LeaveType.UnmarshalJSON()` method wishes to use the *default* unmarshaling logic which does the "hard" part, and just wants to make some final adjustments. So it calls `json.Unmarshal()`:

```
err := json.Unmarshal(b, &r)
```

If we would pass `lt` to unmarshal into, –since `lt` implements `json.Unmashaler`–`LeaveType.UnmarshalJSON()` would be called by the `json` package, effectively causing an infinite "recursion".

Of course, this is not what we want. In order to avoid the infinite recursion, we have to pass a value that does not implement `json.Unmarshaler`, a value whose type does not have an `UnmarshalJSON()` method.

This is where creating a new type comes into the picture:

```
type LT LeaveType
```

The [`type`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) keyword creates a new type called `LT` which is distinct from `LeaveType`. It does not "inherit" any of `LeaveType`'s methods, so `LT` does not implement `json.Unmarshaler`. So if we pass a value of `LT` or `*LT` to `json.Unmarshal()`, it will not result in `LeaveType.UnmarshalJSON()` to be called (by the `json` package).

```
var r *LT = (*LT)(lt)
```

This declares a variable named `r`, whose type is `*LT`. And it assigns the value `lt` converted to `*LT`. The conversion is needed because `lt` is of type `*LeaveType`, so it cannot be assigned to a variable of type `*LT`, but since `LT` has `LeaveType` as its underlying type, `*LeaveType` is convertible to `*LT`.

So `r` is a pointer, it points to the same value as `lt`, it has the same memory layout. So if we use the default unmarshaling logic and "populate" the struct pointed by `r`, then the "same" struct pointed by `lt` will be populated.

See related / similar question: [Call json.Unmarshal inside UnmarshalJSON function without causing stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176625/call-json-unmarshal-inside-unmarshaljson-function-without-causing-stack-overflow/43178272#43178272)

Answer (score 3):

It's casting `lt`, a `LeaveType` pointer, to an `LT` pointer.

`LT` is defined just above by `type LT LeaveType;` to be equivalent to `LeaveType`.

It's doing this for the reasons explained in the comment.

> ```
> // Define a secondary type to avoid ending up with a recursive call to json.Unmarshal
> ```

Whether this is effective or necessary, I don't know.

Comment: The nested type is effective/necessary. See an equivalent issue with the Stringer interface [here](https://play.golang.org/p/IEw_uhdinBJ).

Answer (score 1):

You can see the same effect in play with a simply `Stringer` interface example, where the `fmt.Println` function will try to marshal data into `string` format. If a given value's type has a `String()` method, it will be used in preference to reflection.

This implementation fails (and go vet issues a warning) as it causes infinite recursion:

```
type mystring string
func (ms mystring) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("mystring: %s", ms)
}
```

This version is essential what the original code is doing:

```
type mystring2 string

func (ms mystring2) String() string {
    type mystring2 string // <- local type mystring2 overrides global type
    v := mystring2(ms)

    return fmt.Sprintf("mystring2: %s", v)
}
```

Remove the `type mystring2 string` line and [see what happens](https://play.golang.org/p/IEw_uhdinBJ).