# What does a pair of round brackets syntax expression mean in Go?

Tags: go, syntax, expression, rules

Reading this https://github.com/go-pg/pg/wiki/Writing-Queries#select I see many times this expression:

```golang
(*Book)(nil)
```

Example:

```golang
count, err := db.Model((*Book)(nil)).Count()
```

**What does it mean?**

Comment: This was just asked 3 hours earlier. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60440743/13860

Comment: The selected answer here is more concise and straightforward tho.. Helps for people who are just getting used to Go like me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a type conversion. Assuming the `db.Model` function takes `interface{}`, it sends an nil interface of type `*Book` to the function.

To convert a value `v` to type `Book`, you'd write:

```
Book(v)
```

However, you cannot write `Book(nil)` because `nil` is a pointer and `Book` is not. If you had a type

```
type BookPtr *Book
```

Then you could've written `BookPtr(nil)`. Extending that, you want to write `*Book(nil)`, but that means `*(Book(nil))` which is invalid, hence:

```
(*Book)(nil)
```

Comment: So this is needed in this case only? To convert a nil to *Type interface?

Comment: If you're talking about typecasting, you'd need it if the value is not nil as well, like (*SomePtr)(someValue). You can use this, for instance, to copy a struct value to another with a different but compatible type.

Comment: Isn't converting value to type Book like this: (Book)v

Answer (score 2):

'nil' is to Go what NULL/null is to other languages like C#/Java, etc. The *Variable is just getting the pointer value for the Book object of Model.

So in this case, I believe what's happening here is that (*Book)(nil) is setting the pointer value of the Book object of the Model to nil(/null).

Hope this helps in some way.

Good Resource: https://go101.org/article/nil.html

Comment: So this is needed in this case only? To convert a nil to *Type interface?

Comment: I'm sure there are other times you may want to do this, but commonly I'd say yes.