# How to fix json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []json.RawMessage

Tags: json, go, struct, slice

I want to unmarshal

```
var j = []byte(`[{"major":1},{"minor":0}]`)
```

into

```
type Version struct {
    Major int `json:"major"`
    Minor int `json:"minor"`
}
```

using custom unmarshaler by looping the inner slice:

```
func (h *Version) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var wrapper []json.RawMessage

    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &wrapper)
    if err == nil {
        for _, v := range wrapper {
            if err = json.Unmarshal(v, &h); err != nil {
                break
            }
        }
    }

    return err
}
```

The inner `UnmarshalJSON` triggers

```
json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []json.RawMessage
```

which is strange because the target is a `*Version`. What is wrong here? Play: https://play.golang.org/p/Av59IkYTioS

Comment: You call json.Unmarshal(v, h) which invokes Version.UnmarshalJSON. You simply cannot do this like this. You either need a helper type or redesign.

Comment: Alternatives [1](https://play.golang.org/p/D6VfSV_UGjM), [2](https://play.golang.org/p/VKN3L6zsF8R) if you can rely on the order and number of the objects in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "inner" unmarshal call will recursively call `Version.UnmarshalJSON()`:

```
json.Unmarshal(v, &h)
```

And your error comes from the recursive call: you try to unmarshal `{"major":1}` into `[]json.RawMessage`.

You do not want to call `Version.UnmarshalJSON()` recursively, so create a new type that strips all methods, including the `UnmarshalJSON()`:

```
    type version Version
    h2 := (*version)(h)
    for _, v := range wrapper {
        if err = json.Unmarshal(v, &h2); err != nil {
            break
        }
    }
```

With this change it works, and adding `fmt.Println(msg)` the output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZUjgCrT_b9A)):

```
<nil>
{1 0}
```

Normally this would cause a stack overflow error, but since your second call errors, the recursion breaks. See related: [Call json.Unmarshal inside UnmarshalJSON function without causing stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176625/call-json-unmarshal-inside-unmarshaljson-function-without-causing-stack-overflow/43178272#43178272)