# Copying pointer content in go causing uneccesary overhead?

Tags: go, pointers, copy

If I understood it right, `*s = *(*State)(&state)` copies the content at `&state` to the  s address (after casting `*rawState` to `*State`). But if it is that way, wouldn't it be more efficient to just do `s = (*State)(&state)` instead of copying and `*state` being collected by GC? Or could it lead to side-effects changing the value of s / or other reasons for doing it this way? Thanks!

complete function from [0]:

```
func (s *State) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
type rawState State
var state rawState

dec := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(b))
if s.useJSONNumber {
    dec.UseNumber()
}
err := dec.Decode(&state)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

*s = *(*State)(&state)

return s.Validate()}
```

[0] https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-json/blob/d1018bf93fd9c097133b0159ab8b3c0517a846c9/state.go#L73

Comment: Note that the decoding into a value of type `*rawState` rather than `*State` is necessary to avoid infinitely recursive invocation of `UnmarshalJSON`. The code could be simplified a small bit like so https://play.golang.org/p/UlKeqi7MZ-q which also clarifies the code quite a bit (by ditching the confusing part), in my opinion at least.

Comment: Also, the authors could have just written `*s = State(state)` and the result would be the same. The use of `*s = *(*State)(&state)` has no advantage over the above, all it does is add confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s` is a pointer lets say pointing to location `x` in memory.

`&state` is another pointer at memory location `y`.

the function `UnmarshalJSON` is called with pointer pointing to memory location `x`.

if you do:

`*s = *(*State)(&state)`

this means:
take **pointer** to `y`(`&state`), convert it to the correct pointer type(`*State`), then go to memory location `y`(* at the beginning after `=`) and then copy the value(`=`), to this other memory location `x`(`*s`).

if you, on the other hand, do: `s = (*State)(&state)`

this means:
take **pointer** to `y`(`&state`), convert it to correct pointer type(`*State`), copy that pointer(`=`) to receiver (`s`). The memory location `x` being pointed to by whatever called this function, remains unchanged.

Also when the method is called the pointer itself, received by `UnmarshalJSON` as `s`, is a copy of the pointer at the position it's called from. This `s` inside `UnmarshalJSON` is a value of type `*State` that does not exist beyond `UnmarshalJSON`. This assignment will hence be meaningless beyond `UnmarshalJSON`.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment:

```
*s = *(*State)(&state)
```

Does copy the pointed value. This is required because `s` is a local variable, assigning anything to `s` itself will have no effect once the function returns.

The intention is to assign something where `s` points to, and that is what the above assignment statement does.

The goal of using `rawState` is to create a new type which does not have the `UnmarshalJSON()` method, so passing `*rawState` to `json.Unmarshal()` will not cause a stack overflow.

See related: [Call json.Unmarshal inside UnmarshalJSON function without causing stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176625/call-json-unmarshal-inside-unmarshaljson-function-without-causing-stack-overflow/43178272#43178272)