# How does type conversion internally work? What is the memory utilization for the same?

Tags: string, go, type-conversion, slice

How does Go type conversion internally work?

What is the memory utilisation for a type cast? 
For example:

```
var str1 string
str1 = "26MB string data"
byt := []byte(str1)
str2 := string(byt)
```

whenever I type convert any variable, will it consume more memory?

I am concerned about this because when I try to unmarshall, I get "**fatal error: runtime: out of memory**"

```
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(str1), &obj)
```

str1 value comes from HTTP response, but read using ioutils.ReadAll, hence it contains the complete response.

Comment: Regarding error, is your JSON contains (large) array field? If yes, during *unmarshal*, the function may allocate/deallocate slice frequently, and at some point it may failed to acquire free memory. Also, for *stream* input/data, instead of reading all the data using `ioutil.ReadAll`, you should use [`json.NewDecoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#NewDecoder) which works on `io.Reader` directly.

Comment: @putu Thank you. This might be the issue, cos the data was huge. Can you please tell me how to get insight / indepth details about golang? go docs didnt help me on this... Thank you once again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called *conversion* in Go (not casting), and this is covered in [Spec: Conversions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

> Specific rules apply to (non-constant) conversions between numeric types or to and from a string type. These conversions may change the representation of `x` and incur a run-time cost. All other conversions only change the type but not the representation of `x`.

So generally converting does not make a copy, only changes the type. Converting to / from `string` usually does, as `string` values are immutable, and for example if converting a `string` to `[]byte` would not make a copy, you could change the content of the `string` by changing elements of the resulting byte slice.

See related question: [Does convertion between alias types in Go create copies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253768/does-convertion-between-alias-types-in-go-create-copies/32253871#32253871)

There are some exceptions (compiler optimizations) when converting to / from `string` does not make a copy, for details see [golang: []byte(string) vs []byte(*string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470284/golang-bytestring-vs-bytestring/43470344#43470344).

If you already have your JSON content as a `string` value which you want to unmarshal, you should not convert it to `[]byte` just for the sake of unmarshaling. Instead use [`strings.NewReader()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReader) to obtain an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) which reads from the passed `string` value, and pass this reader to [`json.NewDecoder()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#NewDecoder), so you can unmarshal without having to make a copy of your big input JSON string.

This is how it could look like:

```
input := "BIG JSON INPUT"
dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(input))

var result YourResultType
if err := dec.Decode(&result); err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
```

Also note that this solution can further be optimized if the big JSON string is read from an `io.Reader`, in which case you can completely omit reading it first, just pass that to `json.NewDecoder()` directly, e.g.:

```
dec := json.NewDecoder(jsonSource)

var result YourResultType
if err := dec.Decode(&result); err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: Thank you icza. can you please explain why "when JSON content as a string value which you want to unmarshal, you should not convert it to []byte" ?

Comment: @Hardy Because that copies the string content. If the string is like 25 MB, the result of that conversion will be a distinct byte slice being also 25 MB.

Comment: Ya Ok. Thank you.